# Why does ReactDOM.render need to call function or class components again after creating the virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that React uses `React.createElement()` in recursive way to create the virtual DOM.

For example: if we have an `App` component which has this markup:

```
<div className="app">
  <span>3<span/>
  <Br />
  content 1
<div/>
```

Turns into:

```
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, {}))
```

and this returns this object:

```
{
  type: App, 
  props: {}, 
}
```

and this will call another `React.createElement`

```
React.createElement('div', { className: 'app"}, //children)
```

and this will return this object:

```
{
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    className: 'app',
    children: [
      React.createElement('span', {}, 3), 
      React.createElement('br'),
      'content 1'
    ]
  }
}
```

and this process continues until the whole virtual DOM is created.

Now when `ReactDOM.render()` works it uses these objects to create the real DOM nodes in the browser.

I am reading [this article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/optimizing-react-virtual-dom-explained) that explains the process well but something is confusing to me here,

> If a type attribute holds a string with a tag name—create a tag with all attributes listed under props.
>
> If we have a function or a class under type—call it and repeat the
> process recursively on a result.
>
> If there are any children under props—repeat the process for each
> child one by one and place results inside the parent’s DOM node.

My problem is here:

> If we have a function or a class under type—call it and repeat the
> process recursively on a result

**Why doesn't **ReactDOM.render()** just use the objects created by `React.createElement()` instead of calling the function components again to get the underlying DOM elements? Am I missing something? If `React.createElement()` returns all the details about the component why do we need to do that again??**

Comment: If you only want a static website, then you only need to generate the DOM structure once. If you want the structure to be dynamic, the variables involved need to be re-evaluated.

Comment: @jsejcksn
how this is related to dynamic and static content??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reconciliation in React detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990190/reconciliation-in-react-detailed-explanation)

Comment: @jsejcksn it is a conicidence that the article i referred in the question i reached it through this stackoverflow question, it is just a summerization of the article but doesn't answer mine!

Comment: @jsejcksn the matter is not even related to reconciliation, it is about the first render

Answer (score 1):

I think that part of the problem is that the information in the premise you've provided is oversimplified compared to the actual return value of `React.createElement`. Let's look at a real example with a parent component using an instance of the state hook, and a child component using its props (without any JSX, like in your post):

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script type="module">

const {createElement, useState} = React;

function Count (props) {
  return createElement('span', null, props.value);
}

function App () {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const reactElement = createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    createElement(
      'div',
      null,
      createElement('span', null, 'Count:'),
      ' ',
      createElement(Count, {value: count}),
    ),
    createElement('button', {onClick: () => setCount(n => n + 1)}, 'Increment'),
  );

  console.log(reactElement);
  return reactElement;
}

ReactDOM.render(createElement(App), document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Look at the JS console in your browser when running the example above, and examine the `props` object on the logged react element. Locate the `children` property on `props`, and examine each object in the array. Then repeat this process for every object in the array recursively, all the way down the node hierarchy.

After studying the values, click the "Increment" button in the example, and examine the structure again (recursively) after the rerender. You will find differences in the structure, and some of these differences are caused by the changes to the props object being passed to the function component `Count`. This simple example illustrates one reason why it is necessary to invoke each functional component in every render, however there are many more internal state values created and used by React that depend on the deterministic invocation of these functions on every render.

Comment: I think you approach your answer in a hard way, and why at least `ReactDOM` needs to call function component again in the first render?

Comment: also, when state and props change in the component, it automatically will call the `render` mehod on the component which in turn call `createElement()` that returns the new element with the new data, isn't that enough for ReactDOM to only use these elements without any overwork??